# Show that there exists some vector subspace $F$ with $\textrm{dim}(F)=n-m$ and $F\cap F_i=\left\{0\right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a $K$-vector space of dimension $n$.

Moreover, let $F_1,\ldots,F_k$ be vector subspaces of $E$ with $\textrm{dim}(F_i)\leq m$, where $0<m<n$.

Show that there exists some vector subspace $F$ of $E$ with $\textrm{dim}(F)=n-m$ and $F\cap F_i=\{0\}$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,k$.

---

My first idea is to use that
$$
E\neq \bigcup_{i=1}^k F_i\tag{1}
$$
since all the vector subspaces $F_i$ are proper due to $m<n$. Hence, there must exist some vector subspace $F$ of $E$ such that
$$
E=\bigcup_{i=1}^kF_i\cup F.\tag{2}
$$
But from (1) and (2) it already follows that $F\cap F_i=\{0\}$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k$.

So, I think, it remains to show that $\textrm{dim}(F)=n-m$.

From $F\cap F_i=\{0\}$ it follows that all the sums $F+F_i$ are direct sums, i.e., $F\oplus F_i$.

I am not sure how to continue. One idea would be to use that there always exist vector subspaces $H_i$ of $E$ such that $E$ can be expressed as the direct sums
$$
E=F_i\oplus H_i, \qquad i=1,\ldots,k
$$

Maybe, one needs to compare this to $F\oplus F_i$.

That is, using the dimension formula for direct sums,
$$
n=\textrm{dim}(E)=\textrm{dim}(F_i)+\textrm{dim}(H_i).
$$
Since $\textrm{dim}(F_i)\leq m$ and $m>0$, we have
$$n-m\leq \textrm{dim}(H_i)<n.$$

Since for $x\in E$, the decomposition $x=f_i+h_i$ with $f_i\in F_i$ and $h_i\in H_i$ is unique, doesn't this imply $F=H_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,k$, so that $\textrm{dim}(F)=\textrm{dim}(H_i)$, meaning
$$
n-m\leq\textrm{dim}(F)<n?
$$

Assuming this is correct, I do not see how to deduce $\textrm{dim}(F)=n-m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by MarktMeister in the comments, we assume $char(K)=0$.

Suppose $n=m+1$. Since $E\neq \cup_k F_k$ we can take a vector in $E-\cup_k F_k$, and the subspace $F$ generated by it satisfies the conditions.

Suppose $n=m+2$. As before I can take a vector $v$ in $E-\cup_k F_k$. If we substitute every $F_k$ by $F_k\oplus\langle v \rangle$ we are in the situation of the previous case. Take $w$ as the vector satisfying the condition for the codimension 1 case. The space $F=\langle v,w \rangle$ has dimension 2 and
$$
F\cap F_k=0.
$$
If not, $\alpha v+\beta w \in F_k$ and then $ w \in F_k \oplus \langle v \rangle$, which is a contradiction.

With this idea in mind, I think you can construct a proof by induction.

**Added**

I will rewrite the whole answer from the beginning, since it is not so easy as I thought at a first glance. Nevertheless, the first answer is better to understand the idea, so I will leave it there.

Suppose $m=n-1$. As before.

Assume now that the result is true for $m=n-j$. That is, if $dim(F_k)\leq n-j$ then there exists a subspace $F$ such that $dim(F)=n-m=j$ and $F\cap F_k=0$.

Now we are going to prove that the result is true for $m=n-(j+1)$. Suppose $dim(F_k)\leq n-j-1$, and let $v\in E-\cup_k F_k$. We can define $\tilde{F}_k=F_k\oplus \langle v\rangle$. These spaces satisfy the conditions of the induction hypothesis, since they are of dimension lesser or equal to $n-(j+1)+1=n-j$. Therefore there exists a space $\tilde{F}$ such that $dim(\tilde{F})=j$ and
$$
\tilde{F}\cap \tilde{F}_k=0. \tag{1}
$$

We can define $F=\tilde{F}\oplus \langle{v}\rangle$ and then:

- $dim(F)=j+1$
- $F\cap F_k=0$. If not, there exist $f\in \tilde{F}$ such that $f+\alpha v \in F_k$. But then $f \in \tilde{F}_k$, which is a contradiction.

So $F$ is the desired space and the result is proven.

Comment: Yes, that's true

Comment: To construct the proof by induction you can assume paragraph 1 with $n=m+k$ and proof paragraph 2 (with n=m+k+1)

Comment: If $\alpha v+\beta w \in F_k$ , then $\alpha v+\beta w =u \in F_k$ and $\beta w =u-\alpha v \in F_k \oplus \langle v \rangle$. Then $w \in F_k \oplus \langle v \rangle$.

Comment: In other words, I need to prove by induction that for $n=m+k, k\geq 1$, the vector subspace $F:=\langle v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\rangle$ with
$$
v_i\in E\setminus\bigcup_j F_j\oplus\langle v_1\rangle\oplus\langle v_2\rangle\oplus\ldots\oplus\langle v_{i-1}\rangle,\qquad i=1,2,\ldots,k
$$
does the job?

Comment: I have completed the answer

Comment: OK! So what about my last comment? I think that the $F$ defined there does the job. At least, I cannot see where it fails.

Comment: You must specify how you choose these $v_i$. Thinking about that was the reason for completing the answer, because I couldn't see a formal way to specify the choice.

Comment: It seems like $K$ has to be infinite for the result to hold: let $E = \mathbb F_2^2$, and $F_1 = \langle (1,0) \rangle$, $F_2 = \langle (0,1) \rangle$, $F_3 = \langle (1,1) \rangle$. Then $E = F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_3$.